# Bubble sorting issues

Tags: c#, arrays, bubble-sort

Im currently writing code to sort an array through bubble sort. I've previously written it using a set array that i created and it worked perfectly. However, i tried to change it to a randomly generated array and its now broken. wondered if anyone could give me a hand. thanks in advance.

```
using System;

namespace BubbleSot_Fin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int N = 5;
            int m = 100;
            int i = 1; //n = number of values m = max value in array 
            Random Rand = new Random();


            int[] array = new int[N + 1];

            for ( i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            {
                array[i] = Rand.Next(1, m);      //Randomise the array

            Console.WriteLine("This is the unsorted array");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A[" + i + "] = " + array[i] ); // shows the unsorted numbers
            }




            int[] Bubble = BubbleSort(array);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Array after Bubble Sort");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            for ( i = 0; i < Bubble.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A[" + i + "] = " + Bubble[i]); // shows the numbers after sorting
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static int[] BubbleSort(int[] BSArray)
        {
            int length = array.Length;
            for ( i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)    
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length - 1 - i; j++)
                {
                    if (array[j] > array[j + 1])  
                    {
                        int number = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j + 1];
                        array[j + 1] = number;
                    }
                }
            }
            return BSArray;
        }
    }
}
```

The errors i'm having are that the private and static word for the bubble sort are incorrect.

The errors are :
- CS0106 The modifier 'Private' is not valid for this item
- CS0106 The modifier 'Static' is not valid for this item

Comment: You say “its not broken” but refer to “errors”. Please clarify; if there are errors you need to tell us what they are. Also we can't “give you a hand” over the internet; you have to post what you have and what your problem is [in your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/).

Comment: It is broken. I had it working with a set array that i created (So i input the values) but when i created a randomised array it broke. The errors im having is that it says the private and static part of the method for the bubble sort are not correct for some reason they worked perfectly before but with the randomised array for some reason they dont. i submitted my code at the top you can read through it .

Comment: Just read back through it and me saying its not broken was a typo  it was meant to say " it is now broken"

Comment: Changes have been made ! Give it your best

Comment: You first `for` loop in `Main` - you open a block with `{` but fail to close it. Hence the compiler's confused when it finds a `private static` method declaration *inside* `Main`.